# Series is convergent but it seems it is divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a series:

$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\bigg)}
$$

and I thought it is a divergent series since

$$
\sum{\big(f(x)-g(x)\big)} = \sum{f(x)} - \sum{g(x)}
$$

and so the series equals to

$$
=\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}}
$$

and we know that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ is divergent, so the whole series is divergent. But it turns out that it is convergent and the answer is $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

How do you prove that it is convergent and calculate the answer? The only way I know how to compute an answer for a series is via a geometric series and there seems to be no way to make it into a geometric series!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - Oh wow thank you so much! I totally forgot telescoping series existed!

Comment: Consider $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1$, which diverges, and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1$, which diverges.  But $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-1)$ obviously converges to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule you quoted above $\sum (f(x)-g(x)) = \sum f(x) - \sum g(x)$ is not correct if one or both of the series on the right is divergent.  In this case, both $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$ are divergent.

As indicated in the comments, to evaluate this series, you should telescope the series.

Comment: To further elaborate as to why we cannot say $\sum f(x) - g(x)$ diverges if $\sum f(x)$ and $\sum g(x)$ are individually divergent, consider the example $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty.$$  But we can of course write $$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1},$$ and we know that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$$ is divergent.  Indeed, even more trivially, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0 = 0,$$ yet we could write it as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-1) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1 = \infty - \infty.$$

Comment: The summation rule is valid if both of the individual series converge.  Just check the partial sums.

Comment: @RyanReich Yes you're right.

Comment: @heropup Those are a nice set of examples; I think you should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Write
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}=\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\bigg)$$
and then **telescope**.

Answer (score 6):

First to address your concern,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(f(x)-g(x)\bigg)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(x)$$

is valid only when both $f$ and $g$ are convergent. An infinite sum is nothing more than the *limit* of partial sums, and the above is equivalent to writing,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (S_{n_1}-S_{n_2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} S_{n_1} - \lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n_2}$$

which is only right when *both* the individual limits exist.

---

Now moving on to the problem at hand,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{n}} -\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

$$S_n=1-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

$$S_n=1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

Clearly, we have,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I was wondering why the answer was $1$... and then I saw the edit.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah typo.

Answer (score 4):

Note:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 2}}\right] = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} + \cdots = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

By the way, if $\sum f(n)$ and $\sum g(n)$ diverge, it does not mean $\sum [f(n) - g(n)]$ diverges because, for example,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 2}}\right]$$
converges.

Comment: "The rule you are trying to use to disprove X is incorrect; for a counterexample, observe that X is true". I'm not sure whether that's brilliant or horrible.

Comment: @Rawling If there is a counterexample, then the "theorem" is obviously not true.

Comment: Well yes, but if he's trying to use it to disprove X, X isn't going to be the first counterexample that springs to mind :)

Comment: @Rawling I see what you mean.